# Unable to uninstall Homebrew via CURL

Tags: node.js, git, macos, curl, homebrew

I installed Homebrew on my Mac long time ago, then eventually I updated my Mac to OS X El Capitan some time after. I recently need to update npm using Homebrew as I found some instructions on how to update npm via Homebrew.

I entered `brew update` but returned `fatal: git fetch-pack: expected shallow list` and also tried other commands like `brew upgrade`. It said `Error: Unknown command: upgrade`

I then decided to uninstall Homebrew and re-install it. I tried `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"` and it returned `curl: (1) Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl`

I found that I needed to update curl via Homebrew.. so I am in a dead-end.

Any suggestions?

Comment: try `brew doctor` usualy it more verbose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

curl is just pulling things off the web.  Instead of using it you can go to the link you want

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall

and download that in your normal web browser to a file (right click on the link in this answer with firefox, for example).  Then you just go in a terminal to the directory where you downloaded it and run

```
ruby -e uninstall
```

In fact, if you read the file before you run it, this is more secure too since you actually know what you are going to run.

Comment: Thanks. I switched to the directory and run 'ruby uninstall' and it successfully uninstalled Homebrew.